# How do you embed a template as content in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Is there any way to declare a top-level window as a content template in xaml and recreate it at load time? Essentially I'm trying to do something equivalent to data templating:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:MyType}" >
    <Window>
        ...etc...
    </Window>
</DataTemplate>
```

This works fine at run-time but it generates an error at compile time due to the fact that you're not supposed to use a top-level window to a data template or style etc, so basically I need to replace DataTemplate with a custom class to get around this. I don't actually need support for DataType...data templates set the resource key implicitly to DataType but a bug in WPF means you can't use the relevant attribute on your own types. I can easily get around that by doing things in reverse i.e. specifying the type as the key:

```
<MyClass x:Key="{x:Type my:MyType}" >
    <Window>
        ...etc...
    </Window>
</MyClass>
```

What I need to know though is how to declare MyClass so that the XAML content generates a template that I can create instances from rather than an actual instance of the Window itself.

Comment: You're doing it wrong.  Better to ask how to accomplish the goal you're trying to reach with this.

Comment: Thanks for the response Will but I believe I am taking the correct approach in this particular case. My specific example involves the implementation of dialog boxes in MVVM using data templates to specify which dialog box window to create in response to a given view model. Conceptually this is no different to attaching a child control to a parent window, the child just happens to be a top level window. Data templates are the standard mechanism in MVVM in which to achieve this and do in fact work despite that XAML error, using something too different would be architecturally inconsistent IMO.

Comment: Then you wouldn't have a Window but a UserControl as the root of the DataContext.  So, no, nope.  You're doing your best to avoid the pit of success.  You shouldn't.

Comment: I think you're making the incorrect assumption that I'm relying on the framework to generate content. I'm not. The DataTemplate LoadContent() method allows you to dynamically create templated instances at run-time. Conceptually and practically there is no difference whether that content is a UserControl or a top-level window, I just happen to be using it to create the latter. Either way my exact reasons for doing it are irrelevant. Templates, styles and various other classes turn XAML content into templates instead of instances, my question is how do they do it and how can I do it myself?

Comment: You say the reasons why are irrelevant, yet you hint at them.  So your real goals are more aligned with templating rather than UI.  Again, if you would ask about how to accomplish your goals, you probably would get a better answer.  I've done both, so might be able to point you in the right direction...